# Safari executing extra index in for..in loop

Tags: javascript, safari

I am facing a weird issue only in Safari. At instances, where I am using a for..in loop, I find Safari going overboard and executing the loop an extra time than the available number of keys. I am not sure if Safari wants to continue on an endless spree as it breaks as soon as it tries to fire an undefined key.

Has someone else encountered and hopefully fixed this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that has a loop demonstrating your problem.  It would also be beneficial to report the version of Safari.

Comment: post relevant code, please

Answer (score 0):

A couple things need to occur for this to work properly:

- Make sure you are iterating over an object instead of an array. If it's an array use a for with the length.
- Make sure you are using the hasOwnProperty() function to verify you aren't iterating over unexpected properties.

See "Example: Iterating over the properties of an object" on the MDN documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty